# Dependency Injection of builder.Configuration is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, configuration

I want to access secrets through `IConfiguration` and I'm setting it up like this in `Program.cs`:

```cs
namespace Project
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            
            builder.Configuration
                .AddJsonFile("secrets.json");

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(builder.Configuration);
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IS3Service, S3Service>();

            var app = builder.Build();

            ...

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to access it from another class `configuration` is null:

```cs
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;

using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using PixelFlow.Models.S3Service;

namespace PixelFlow.Services
{
    public interface IS3Service
    {
        public Task<bool?> ObjectExistsAsync(string fileName);
        public Task<GetObjectResponse?> GetObjectAsync(string fileName);
        public Task<ListObjectsPage?> ListObjectsAsync(int maxObjectsCount, string nextPageCursor);
        public Task<bool> UploadObjectAsync(string filePath, string fileName);
    }

    public class S3Service : IS3Service
    {
        private static IConfiguration _configuration;
        
        public S3Service(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        private static readonly AmazonS3Config s3Config = new()
        {
            ServiceURL = _configuration["Secrets:S3_SERVICE_URL"] //System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
        };

        private static AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(
            _configuration["Secrects:S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID"], _configuration["Secrets:S3_ACCESS_KEY"], s3Config);

        public async Task<bool?> ObjectExistsAsync(string fileName)
        {
            ...
        }

        public async Task<GetObjectResponse?> GetObjectAsync(string fileName)
        {
            ...
        }

        public async Task<ListObjectsPage?> ListObjectsAsync(int maxObjectsCount, string nextPageCursor)
        {
            ...
        }

        public async Task<bool> UploadObjectAsync(string filePath, string fileName)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of net core are you using?

Comment: I'm using .net6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create an interface for the S3Service, then implement the interface in the S3Service and then register your S3Service in the `program.cs` file like the following:

**1. Create interface**

```
public interface IS3Service
{
    public bool UploadFileToS3(string filePath); // Example interface method
}
```

**2. Implement interface**

```
public class S3Service : IS3Service // <- Add this 
{
    private static IConfiguration _configuration;
}

public S3Service(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

public bool UploadFileToS3(string filePath)
{
    // Upload File to S3 implementation
}
```

**3. Register the `S3Service` in the `program.cs` file**

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IS3Service, S3Service>();
```

With the above in place you should be able to get the configuration values from the `secrets.json`.
Try it out and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Why do I have to register S3Service? From my understanding `AddTransient<>()` will make S3Service available in constructors like `IConfiguration`, but I don't want that. Am i wrong?

Comment: As the `IConfiguration` service has been added as a dependency, the service using it (S3Service) also needs to be registered as a dependency for it to work. You want to register you services as dependencies as it is good practice called _Inversion of control_ and stands for the _I_ part in the SOLID principles. _Inversion of control_ means you are letting the .Net framework doing the object initialization of the services instead of you as a developer dont have to worry about it which is what you want.

Comment: Alright I understand but even after doing what you said the error is still happending. I updated the original question with what you suggested.

Comment: IConfiguration is getting injected successfully when I use @IceCode's  code above.  How are you instantiating the S3Service instance that is getting the NullReferenceException?  That's not included in your example.  E.g., if you're explicitly creating it via a call to its constructor rather than using an instance created via DI, its IConfiguration dependency will be null.

Comment: It was a problem with the client initialization which was static and outside the S3Service constructor, my bad.